# How can i embed trello cards dynamically using GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm new programming in google app script, what i want to do is to put a column with links and buttons next to the links so if the user click the button should see the trello card attached to the link, i will post what I've done but its not really working properly

```js
<script>
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(link => {
  var document = document.getElementById('myLink');
  document.href = link;
  }).cardLinkReceiver(); 
  </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue as you some weeks ago i solved using this code

```js
<blockquote class="trello-card">
  <a id="card">Trello Card</a>
</blockquote>

<script>

  (() => {

    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(() => {

      const tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://p.trellocdn.com/embed.min.js";

      tag.addEventListener('load', () => {

        //can start doing something cool...

        const yourDocument = document.querySelector('#card');

        yourDocument.href = 'your card url';

        window.TrelloCards.load(document); // <-- this triggers the lookup
      });

      document.body.append(tag);

    }).cardLinkReceiver();

  })();
```

1. First you do the async function cardLinkReceiver()
2. Load the library withSuccessfullHandler
3. Attach a load listener to ensure the library is loaded